# .NET Entity Framework, clean way to implement it?

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, linq, entity-framework

I'm currently learning LINQ especially SQL requests with the entity framework.
I used to write native SQL-queries before, and I've implemented it with one class in my projects called "SQL_Connection" or something.
So I had all my SQL-procedures stored in one class.

Now as I'm willed to learn the entity framework the right and cleanest way from beginning, I'm asking myself where do I put all those linq-procedures I create during a project.
Do expierienced people put them in the class-file of the related class, or are they using a big sql-class where all those procedures are stored in?

Comment: cleanest ? programming doesn't involve "est" things !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm asking myself where do I put all those linq-procedures I create during a project.

Where you create them.

If you are not totally ignorant on .NET you will have a TON of LINQ queries and only SOME will be EF related - the syntax is the same. You will use LINQ in your code to sum and aggregate in memory arrays, and do a lot of things.

The beauty of LINQ is that all changes to the underlying provider are isolated and / or checked by the compiler, so there is no need to have all in one place "in case I rename a table".

I keep the LINQ where I need it. This allows me to isolate layers without having a mother of all queries class. Especiall as some of the LINQ queries are multi step queries involving one or more data access then grouping and correlating in memory.

Seriously, the "one class to rule them all" (sql) is an artefact of the fact that SQL is a string, so in case of a database change you need to find all SQL that touches that changed element and that please without going through tons of code. This is absolutely not needed with LINQ.

Comment: Thank you for answer! To be honest, I'm a .NET software-developer since 3 years and never came in touch with LINQ. Thats why it's hard for me to understand, how to use it the right way. So are you going to say, that it's better to request a list with my objects from SQL and then afterwards, I'm going to pick everything needed out with LINQ ?

Comment: No. As LINQ has delayed execution your interface exposes an IQueryable and the filtering can be done wherever you want it. Only when data is actually asked for will the query be executed. Linq basics - before asking how it can be done nicely, learn what it CAN do first please.

Answer (score 0):

That's up to your pleasure. Answering the question: do create BLL classes for your related set of objects. By this, a minor change won't make you itchy. Assume you added a new column to a table, having that table's (and other related ones') operations located easily is good, right? Avoid too big files. Try to stay modular and etc.

If you need a reading, check out [this Wiki link about MVC architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).